# Is "entitled" wrong to use in place of "the title for"?

Tags: word-choice

> In order for this extension to work, there are DLL files that must be available to the Windows system PATH. For information on how to do this, see the FAQ entitled "How do I add my PHP directory to the PATH on Windows".

Is the FAQ really "entitled" "How do I add my PHP directory to the PATH on Windows", or is it "titled" "How do I add my PHP directory to the PATH on Windows"?

Comment: Either the stative _titled_ or the passive causative _entitled_ will work, and they both mean the same thing. Morphology is rarely of use in English.

Answer (score 1):

That is a perfectly normal use. See meaning 1 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entitled#Adjective).